Layperson wanting to know if their novel turbine design is silly
Vertical axis wind turbines are limited by the fact that one side must constantly move into the wind. That got me thinking about rotors that change shape to more optimally move into the wind. The simplest version of my idea (doors that are blown open and closed) is illustrated below.
Sorry for the sketchy animation. I'll make a better one later, if it's worth the trouble, but I have no engineering background, so wanted to ask this community if the idea is at least interesting.

Being honest, is this just dumb? Either way, thanks for looking at it.

I'm not sure it's likely to gain enough to justify the extra complexity. Simple versions just using barrels cut in half can achieve around 40% efficiency, and the maximum theoretically possible is apparently a bit under 60%, so I doubt this would gain more than 10% or so (though depending on how you look at it that would be a 25% gain compared to the barrel version, which could be pretty worthwhile if you could build it cheaply enough). But two half-barrel turbines probably produce more output for less money. Could easily work out if you're limited more by space than money though.

So are the blades spring loaded? or feedback controlled? how often will they need maintenance? if offshore what is the cost?

there is a flying vehicle design that uses something like that for propulsion ... also used for steering ships ... cyclorotors

Unless this question is modified to request a quantifiable aspect, it's going to become an opinion/chat and vanish eventually.

@SolarMike - The blades are just loosely attached to the poles, and are naturally blown open and closed by the flow.

@CarlSmith so no bearings? expected life?

I just started with the simplest design that works at all. There are lots of improvements you could make, but I'm a programmer, so it's not something I'm qualified to explore myself.

For example, I'd use blades with solid frames, and rubber skins, so the blades form concavities when catching the wind, but stay flat on the way back round.

I'd also connect many small, cheap turbines together using belts and gears, and have them drive a single generator. But, as I say, I'm not a engineer, so am just making up stuff that seems like it'd work to me, without any qualification whatsoever.

It's going to be pretty noisy I would imagine, with all that banging closed going on, especially in high wind conditions.

It wouldn't bang. That's just the simplest design that illustrates the principle. Even with that design, it will not necessarily hit itself (I made a crude prototype). As the blades open, and swing round to the back, the wind stops them from hitting the poles. This is partly just due to the air being in the way, but also due to a slight delay: By the time the blades swing round, the flow is no longer directly backwards, enough to keep the blades from connecting with anything. In any case, you can design different turbines using the same basic idea.

What you propose is a type of vertical-axis wind turbine about which much has been written. There is no reason why it would not work. It would be eminently possible to gear the blades so they open and close automatically as the entire assembly rotates, at just the right time to maximize energy capture. So let's expand a bit on your original design, as follows:
Imagine now that each "shutter" in your design is instead  a long, slender wing that converts energy in the passing airflow into rotary work by generating a lift vector that points at least partly tangent to the direction of rotation of the whole (cylindrical) frame. Furthermore, we gear the wing so its angle of attack varies as the frame rotates about its vertical axis. Then we add more vertical wings around the cylinder so there is always at least one wing capturing energy, while the wing directly opposite it is feathered to minimize drag.
We have now transformed an ordinary horizontal-axis windmill in the form of a disc of (radial) blades connected to a rotating hub into an equivalent windmill in which the (axial) blades are instead arrayed cylindrically. This is the classic example of a vertical-axis wind turbine.
